# Windows 98 remote support over dial-up?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-98

A certain octogenarian in my family lives in a far-away state and uses an ancient (circa 2001) computer for doing email. It works "just fine" (so she says) and she doesn't want to replace it. Whatever. I swear, next time I'm there, I'm going to sneak in a newer computer and she'll never notice the difference.

Any way, she's now having some computer problems and wants me to help fix it. Aparantly, six years ago, I logged into her computer remotely and did just that.

How the heck did I login to a WIndows 98 box remotely (over dial-up no less), and how on earth could I do it today (all the modern remote support tools I found require WinXP and above)?

Comment: I was about to suggest http://copilot.com/ - but it requires win2k or newer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symantec's **pcAnywhere** (compatible with Windows 98 up to version 12) supports dial-up networking. it was very popular 'back in the days' and it is still around.

at softpedia.com you'll get the [trial version 12](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Remote-Utils/pcAnywhere.shtml)

if 25 MB is too big to download, you may try an older version. here's a [download link](ftp://ftp.univ-montp2.fr/pub/pc/win95/Demo/pcANYWHERE32%208.0.exe) for version 8 (8MB, 30 days trial). note: this version is not compatible with XP, you'll need 11.5 or better on your side.

Comment: I happen to know from experience this is true. Before I retired my company headquarters used to communicate with my remote computer using "pcAnywhere" via dial-up connection and Windows 98. It was a long time ago :)

Answer (score 4):

VNC maybe?  It's certainly [available for Windows 98](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvnc.html).  If it was indeed VNC, the original executable might be conveniently lying somewhere on the hard drive.  Have her do file search for `*vnc*.exe` and see what appears.

**Or:** I don't mean to offend, but it could be a construct of her imagination.  While working at a helpdesk during college, I fielded a question from a retired professor's spouse of similar age.  She was *insistent* that one of our techs had actually come over to her house and fixed the issue "just a few weeks ago".  I queried her call history.  The housecall occured in 1995.  She called me in 2007.

Answer (score 1):

probably used Windows NetMeeting

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you will need to setup her computer to run remote desktop, but SKYPE and MSN messenger include both this feature, and I guess she's using one.